# How does C know how long a char* is after assignment?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I know that there are two ways to use 'strings' in C--

```
char foo[NUMBER] = "bar";

char *foo = "bar";
```

I also know that, due to the way C stores the former, they are immutable--I can't reassign a new string to the array. So to have a mutable string var I have to use a pointer. But how does C store/know the length of the the new string I'm assigning--

```
*foo = "hello";
```

This string is longer than the first string, so if C had seen that it only needed 3 bytes to the store 'foo' at the first assignment, and thus allocated that memory, how does it change that, if it has to make foo point to a longer string?

Comment: Did you mean `foo = "hello";`? (without dereferencing `foo`)

Comment: "I also know that..."   that statement is false, a char array may be written to

Comment: yep, forgot semicolons, and @M.M, I thought you weren't allowed to reassign after initialization?

Comment: @BenGranger variables that are not `const` may be modified at any time, e.g. `int x = 5;  x = 6; x = 7;`

Comment: But what happens if I reassign and the length changes, if C has already allocated x number of bytes in memory to fit "bar" and "bar" only

Comment: @BenGranger the length can't change. You seem very confused ,  I'd suggest starting with a book or other tutorial that explains things like variables. [Here are some book ideas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Comment: Try compiling your code. If there are any warnings, this probably means your code is invalid. Read them. What does your compiler say when you try to compile `*foo = "hello";`? You should always use a high warning level.

Comment: Yea, I have -Wall on, that error is in there, among many others, its tricky coming from C++ where I don't really have to think about strings on a low level

Comment: If your code produces warnings you don't understand, your question should be *what do these warnings mean and how do I fix them?*  If you try to discuss the code from any other perspective, you will arrive at this question sooner or later. Skip the waste of time and cut straight to business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write down double quoted strings in 'C', those are stored into Text Segment (constant data) of the memory.

`char foo[NUMBER] = "bar"` : copies `"bar"` into data segment.

`char *foo = "bar"` : `char *foo` stored into data memory,`foo` only points to `"bar"` stored in text segment.

You can anytime change the location where `foo` should point by `foo = "hello"`.

Comment: Meaning, the array format stores the string/char array in memory, whereas the pointer format only stores the pointer in memory, which can be changed since its a constant size?

Comment: @BenGranger: The memory allocation for a program is generaly categorized as : Text Segment (Code and Constants such as strings stored in ROM/HDD and may be moved to RAM for execution) and Data Segment (Stack,Heap,Global Variables,allocated on RAM). Now `char foo[NUMBER]` is a array which may be stored on Stack or Glabal Data memory, taking `NUMBER` bytes. `char *foo` is also stored into data memory taking '4'*** bytes. But the double quoted strings are stored onto Text Segment. Thus compiler can simply generate instructions to modify where `foo` is pointing to at any place in the code.

Comment: Neither stack nor heap are included in the common definition of Data Segment.

Comment: @kaylum ,you are correct but I am trying to make it less confusing as possible for beginner.

Comment: What if `NUMBER` was `3` above? There should be no `NUMBER` in the direct initialization.

Comment: `foo = "hello"; `, not `*foo = "hello"; `.

Answer (score 0):

The string was already stored in your program's constant section because you put it in the source code. Assigning from a string literal doesn't allocate any new memory, it just changes the pointer (which is a constant size) to point at the location where the string already exists.

Comment: So when compiled, every single thing in double quotes, is stored in a different place in memory, and as the program runs, foo is changed to point to each one when I 'assign' a new string to it?